# fwrite php script into a file

Tags: php, fwrite

Basically, I can write html tags/text etc etc to the file. All that is fine. However, I need to be able to write some actual php into the file and I'm completely oblivious of how I should go about doing this.

Anyway here is what I have got to help better demonstrate my situation:

```
$path = substr(md5(time() . md5(rand())), 0, 8);
$dir = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 4);
$fpath = "b/" . $dir "/" . $path;
$file = 'index.php';

$handle = fopen($fpath . '/' . $file, 'w') or die ('cannot create the file'); 
include template.php;
fwrite($handle, $pt1 . $pt2 . $pt3);
```

Inside the template.php I have variables holding a lot of html in $pt1,$pt2,$pt3 
But, inbetween each 'pt' I need to have some actuall php.

So for example sake say I need $this inbetween each 'pt' and the $this being:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
echo "hello";
}else{
echo "bye";
} 
?>
```

How would I do it?

*The actual creating of the file and paths is fine though but, I know that it may look very unusual however, I like it that way. It's simply adding the php scripts to the php file.

- also I have tried sticking the scripts inside variables but, it seems to just print them out as plain text in the file rather than executing them.

Comment: I guess you can use PHP's [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), and insert that code 3 tokens after a T_VARIABLE named "pt" :) Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: Hmm, I will have a look into that as I've never heard of the tokenizer before. Though regarding the reason why* I'm doing this is because I need a template for the users saves, of which has to have php embeded within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does inbetween each pt means `$p1 . $var . $pt2`?

Try something like this:

```
<?PHP
$var = '<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
echo "hello";
}else{
echo "bye";
} 
?>';
echo $pt1 . $var . $pt2;
?>
```

**Edit:**

Also, you can wrap long content into a variable using

```
<?PHP
$var = <<< 'PHP'
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){
echo "hello";
}else{
echo "bye";
} 
?>
PHP;
$pt1 = 'before';
$pt2 = 'after';
echo "$pt1 $var $pt2";
?>
```

Comment: Oh, wait my bad. Putting them into variables again for the second time does work. I don't know what I did wrong the first time but thanks for getting my to give it another shot as it is executing the php now.